# How to Capture the Values from the drop down in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Please Help me in a solution to get the value fields for the below mentioned code into a variable

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$DropDowns1$CountryCityDropDownList" onchange="validate(this);setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$DropDowns1$CountryCityDropDownList\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_DropDowns1_CountryCityDropDownList" class="DropDownMedium">
<option value="-1">Select</option>
<option value="7099">4</option>
<option value="7092">a, b, c1</option>
<option value="7093">a,b,c3</option>
<option value="7123">AA, Testing</option>
<option value="7089">aaaa</option>
<option selected="selected" value="240">AL, Alabaster</option>
<option value="244">AL, Albertville</option>
<option value="250">AL, Alexander City</option>
<option value="275">AL, Andalusia</option>
<option value="281">AL, Anniston</option>
<option value="285">AL, Arab</option>
<option value="297">AL, Athens</option>
<option value="393">AL, Atmore</option>
<option value="312">AL, Auburn</option>
<option value="303">AL, Bay Minette</option>
<option value="466">AL, Bessemer</option>
```

I should be able to capture the value="7099" value="7123" so on into seperate variable

Answer (score 0):

Add a Regular Expression Extractor with regex `value="(.*?)"` and Match No. set to `-1`.

That will save all the matches in an array. and you will be able to access the values by ${varName_1}, ${varName_2} ... ${varName_matchNr}